# Problems with long lists as input of set_xticklabels (Misaligned)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am following the NMT with attention (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb) tutorial and I am applying it for my own use case. Unfortunately, when I try to plot the attention weigths, I get alignment problems of the x-axis if the input is too long (e.g. 14 instead of 7).

**In this code block, the plotting works as expected:**

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_attention():
    attention = np.array([[7.78877574e-10, 4.04739769e-10, 6.65854022e-05, 1.63362725e-04,
    2.85054208e-04, 8.50252633e-04, 4.58042100e-02],
   [9.23501700e-02, 5.69618285e-01, 1.80586591e-01, 9.78111699e-02,
    2.71992851e-02, 9.59911197e-03, 2.54837354e-03]])



    sentence = ['<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>'] 
    predicted_sentence = ['it', 's']



    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.matshow(attention, cmap='viridis')

    fontdict = {'fontsize': 14}

    ax.set_xticklabels([''] + sentence, fontdict=fontdict, rotation=90)
    ax.set_yticklabels([''] + predicted_sentence, fontdict=fontdict)

    plt.show()

plot_attention()
```

**but with more elements in the list "sentence", it seems to misalign:**

```
def plot_attention():
    attention = np.array([[7.78877574e-10, 4.04739769e-10, 6.65854022e-05, 1.63362725e-04,
    2.85054208e-04, 8.50252633e-04, 4.58042100e-02, 7.78877574e-10, 4.04739769e-10, 6.65854022e-05, 1.63362725e-04,
    2.85054208e-04, 8.50252633e-04, 4.58042100e-02],
   [9.23501700e-02, 5.69618285e-01, 1.80586591e-01, 9.78111699e-02,
    2.71992851e-02, 9.59911197e-03, 2.54837354e-03, 7.78877574e-10, 4.04739769e-10, 6.65854022e-05, 1.63362725e-04,
    2.85054208e-04, 8.50252633e-04, 4.58042100e-02]])




    sentence = ['<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>', '<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>'] 
    predicted_sentence = ['it', 's']


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.matshow(attention, cmap='viridis')

    fontdict = {'fontsize': 14}

    ax.set_xticklabels([''] + sentence, fontdict=fontdict, rotation=90)
    ax.set_yticklabels([''] + predicted_sentence, fontdict=fontdict)

    plt.show()

plot_attention()
```

[I expect the x-axis to be perfectly aligned and that all elements of the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZT7l.png) are shown (not every second one as it is right now)

Comment: If I run your code, I get a different figure where every single tick is shown. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks for your help! can you show me a screenshot? I use matplotlib 3.0.3 and it doesn't work for me on the cloud and locally. Copy+Pasting it in a new google colab should reproduce the error

Comment: @Sheldore I have edited the question, please check again

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/0ObXErG) is what I get on `2.2.2`. Click on the image to see full view

Comment: Even Google colab 3.0.3 gives me same result

Comment: @Sheldore Please try the second code snippet, sorry if this was not clear. I am trying to map the following sentence:
    sentence = ['<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>', '<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>'] 
NOT: 
['<start>', 'hace', 'mucho', 'frio', 'aqui', '.', '<end>']

Comment: @Sheldore The problem arises when the sentence list has more than 5-7 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are only setting the tick-labels without specifying the positions of the ticks. Whenever you modify the tick labels, you should *always* first set the tick positions. So, do the following in your code

```
ax.set_xticks(range(len(sentence)))
ax.set_yticks(range(len(predicted_sentence)))
ax.set_xticklabels(sentence, fontdict=fontdict, rotation=90)
ax.set_yticklabels(predicted_sentence, fontdict=fontdict)
```

[image]